# Add non breaking space within razor helper method

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-4

How can I include a non-breaking space (`&nbsp;`) within a Razor helper method? Here's the helper in question:

```
@helper RenderClipResult(Clip clip, IList<string> searchTerms)
{
    <div class="result">
        <!-- other clip stuff -->
        @if (clip.ThirdPartyMaterials != null && clip.ThirdPartyMaterials.Count > 0)
        {
            <p>
                <span class="heading">Third Party Material</span><br/>
                @foreach (var material in clip.ThirdPartyMaterials)
                {
                    &nbsp; @AddElement("Description", material.Description, searchTerms) @AddElement("Cost", material.Cost, searchTerms)
                    <br />
                }
            </p>
        }
    </div>
}
```

`AddElement` is another custom helper. The output I'm looking for is something like this:

```
Third Party Material
 first entry
 second entry
 third entry
```

I could wrap the `AddElement` line in a span tag for styling but it's another html tag and css rule, just to indent some text by a single character width. Might have to go that way as Razor is not able to parse the space

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Add `@:` before your non-breaking space html code

Comment: Thanks Pierre, that worked out great for me too. Any chance you could point me to some related documentation?

Comment: @ChaithanyaM Look at "Mixing code and plain text (alternate)" in this post: http://haacked.com/archive/2011/01/06/razor-syntax-quick-reference.aspx/

Comment: I was just looking for this...+1 :)

Comment: This didn't work for me in my situation, so as stupid as it sounds I did this instead: <span>&nbsp;</span> - this worked, but I have used the "@&nbsp;" method as well.

Answer (score 0):

The second option is to use construction: @Html.Raw(" ") . This also can be user with multiplied nbsp-signs, so you can put result of the string builder to RAW function.